# Issues with StdDraw in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, stddraw

So I've got some code that redraws a picture in order of color frequency. It works! 
But my issue is with StdDraw, or at least I think it is. While my code reproduces the image faithfully, it introduces really odd artifacts in a checkered pattern, like so.[image: Batman.jpg] Is this an issue with StdDraw, or with my code?

Here's the code:

```
for (int z = colorandcoords.size()-1; z >= 0; z--) {
        for (int i = 0; i < colorandcoords.get(z).getFrequency(); i++) {

            StdDraw.setPenColor(colorandcoords.get(z).getColor());
            StdDraw.point(colorandcoords.get(z).getX(i), height - (colorandcoords.get(z).getY(i)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: And where is the code?

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot that. Added it.